# select values submitted with react-hook-form are always undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've noticed that when using a `select` element with [`react-hook-form`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form), it will *always* result in RHF sending a payload with the associated `select` values being `undefined`.

```
import { Form, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export const ExampleForm = () => {
    const { register, control, getValues } = useForm({
        resolver: zodResolver(zodSchema)
    });

    const initialValues = useMemo(() => ({
        selectTest: "Default select value",
        inputTest:  "Default input value"
    }), []);    

    return (
        <Form action="/api/endpoint" control={control}>
            <select 
                {...register("selectTest")}
                defaultValue={initialValues["selectTest"]}>
                    <option value="Default select value">Default</option>
                    <option value="Another value">Another option</option>
            </select>

            <input 
                {...register("inputTest")}
                defaultValue={initialValues["inputTest"]}
                placeholder="Placeholder" />
        </Form>
    );
};
```

Despite this, when using the exact same approach on an `input` element, it will work completely as expected.

Where am I going wrong?